# $\int_C\limits{\vec E}\cdot{d \vec r}$ inside and outside a perfect conductor with an intriguing result

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Consider a **solid** conductor of any arbitrary shape and with charges lying on its surface. Therefore, the electric field is zero inside but nonzero outside. Now consider two points, P and Q,  on the surface of the conductor. Let us join P and Q, by two different paths. The path $C_{\rm out}$ lies entirely **outside** the conductor where the field is nonzero, and $C_{\rm in}$, lying entirely **inside** the conductor where the field is zero. But since the line integral of the electric field is **path-independent**, we must have

$$\int\limits_{P,C_{\rm out}}^{Q}{\vec E}\cdot{d \vec r}=\int\limits_{P,C_{\rm in}}^{Q}{\vec E}\cdot{d \vec r}.$$ Since the electric field is zero inside, the integral on the right is zero. But by the above equality, the integral on the left must also be zero. This feels rather nonintuitive. So I want to ask if the logic is correct i.e. if the integral on the left really vanishes. If not, where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_P^Q \vec E \cdot d\vec r = -\int_P^Q (\nabla V)\cdot d\vec r = V(P)-V(Q)$$

What you've shown is that the potential difference between any two points on the conductor is zero, which is indeed correct.

Comment: Oh-Oh! Facepalm.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: the integral $I[{\rm P,Q}]\equiv \int_P^Q {
\bf E}\cdot d{\bf r}$ is zero when P and Q lie on the surface of the same  conductor. This is because the surface is an equipotential and $I[{\rm P,Q}]$ is the difference in potential between P and Q, so  $I[{\rm P,Q}]=0$.

All this assumes not time depenedent magnetic field, so ${\rm curl\,}{\bf E}={\bf 0}$.